# Checking conditions in fe_page template for Contao

Tags: templates, meta-tags, contao

I am now working with contao fe_page template for generating meta tags. Now i need to display a meta tag based on a condition. That is

```
    if (condition a){
        meta tag =a
}
else {
        meta tag = b
}
```

The condition is "whether the news module is used in that page or not". 
 How can I check for dat condition in fe_page template? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What kind of meta tag do you want to insert under which condition exactly? May be you should do it the other way around: add a meta tag within a `parseArticles` hook or a news template via `$GLOBAL['TL_HEAD'][] = …`.

Comment: I am using fe_page template in all pages. And in all pages, I need to display a meta tag based on a condition and it is:  1) If news module is used in that page and if that contains an image, then write the meta tag as <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">. 2), If no image is used, then write another another meta tag.  Can we check this condition in fe_page template? If yes, how is it possible? If no, then what are the other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stead of checking it in your `fe_page` template, you can do the following in your `news_full` template:

```php
<?php

if ($this->addImage)
{
    $GLOBALS['TL_HEAD'][] = '<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">';
    $GLOBALS['TL_HEAD'][] = '<meta name="twitter:image" content="' . $this->singleSRC . '">';
}
```

As you can see this also adds a `twitter:image` meta attribute with the news article's teaser image.

Instead of doing it in a `news_full` template, you could also do it in a `parseArticle` hook, which gives you a little more control, in case you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying with parseArticle hook.

Comment: public function parseArticles($objTemplate, $arrRow, $module) {
        if (!empty($arrRow['singleSRC'])) {
            $GLOBALS['TL_HEAD'][] = '<meta name="property" content="valuesss">'; 
        }
        else {
            $GLOBALS['TL_HEAD'][] = '<meta name="property" content="no image">'; 
        } }.... Is this the method? If my page doesn't contain news module, I need to display <meta name="property" content="no image">. This cannot be achieved with this method. How this else condition can be made possible?

Comment: If you use the `parseArticle` hook, you also need to check the module type. e.g. `if ($module->type == 'newsreader')`. Something like `<meta name="property" content="no image">` seems unnecessary.

Comment: For the pages using news module, this is right. And what can I do for pages that are not using news module? This parseArticle hook will get initiated only if the page contains a news module. One option is to write in all page templates, the other condition, which I think is not the write method. Can we give the two conditions, in a common place, so that we just have to write in one place?

Comment: Why do you need `<meta name="property" content="no image">`? What purpose does this meta tag serve?

Comment: Actually my conditions are: if(Newsmodule is present and image also present in it) { <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">} else { <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">}.... This is what I need to achieve in the head section of every page templates.  ParseArticle is possible, only if the page contains news module. The other condition cannot be checked in that case. Is there a solution?

Comment: You could add the following to your fe_page template: `<meta name="twitter:card" content="<?= $GLOBALS['twitter_card_type'] ?: 'summary' ?>">` and then simply set `$GLOBALS['twitter_card_type'] = 'summary_large_image'` in your `parseArticle` hook or `news_full` template accordingly. Not pretty, but gets the job done.